# Is there a generalization of integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

In the original integration by part formula there are two functions $u(x)$ and $v(x)$. What if the integral involves another function $w(x)$ as well?

Second of all, I know that there is a several variable version of integration by substitution, is there any several variables version of integration by parts?

I read the [wikipedia page on the higher dimensional case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), and I found it really complicated.  Could anyone show me an example on how to do the higher dimensional case?

Comment: Read the wikipedia page- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Comment: Specifically, [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Higher_dimensions) of it (for your second question) ...